# Google Disk blocking file transfer

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to resolve an issue that has been bothering me for weeks now. We have a website project that we have taken over from other company. The website displays clients short pornographic videos. I am not sure if I can share the link so for now I wont as it is not that important. The way it works is that on the homepage we display videos with a source comming from google disk like this: src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=&export=download" where the $code is ID of the video on google.
The problem is this - videos work fine for a minute or so but than google starts blocking them.
The videos give a response of 403 which by the documentation means that limits are exhausted.
[image: example of the blocking]
I have tried to solve it in console.google.com by finding limitations or so but that did not do the trick.
This is what you will get if you paste the video URL to the browser: [image]

We have also found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284158/google-drive-api-were-sorry-but-your-computer-or-network-may-be-sending) but we do it differently so it did not help.

Could anyone please help to solve this?

Thank you.
Best Regards,
Josef

We have tried solving this through google console but it did not help.